# ARM deployment occasionally fails due to mismatching identity

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template that deploys a Windows Web App that has two slots (production and staging).
The template is integrated with Azure DevOps build and release pipelines and deployed using the *Azure resource group deployment* task.

The problem I am encountering is that occasionally the pipeline will fail when the template is getting deployed with the following error message

```
2019-07-25T07:49:22.3093628Z There were errors in your deployment. Error code: MismatchingResourceIdentityPrincipalId.
2019-07-25T07:49:22.3213510Z ##[error]The principalId '5e7127c4-5a72-49b4-9747-7311e984e1c8' on the resource's Identity property is invalid and must be empty or match the existing principalId of '0471a448-0e77-48cd-b39a-01d8d1f3c5e3'.
2019-07-25T07:49:22.3221635Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

For reference, this is how the identities are configured in the ARM template

```
...

"resources": [{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
  "name": "myApp",
  "kind": "app",
  "identity": {
    "principalId": "0471a448-0e77-48cd-b39a-01d8d1f3c5e3",
    "tenantId": ".......",
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
  "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
  "name": "myApp/Staging",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', 'myApp')]"
  ],
  "kind": "app",
  "identity": {
    "principalId": "5e7127c4-5a72-49b4-9747-7311e984e1c8",
    "tenantId": "......",
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
  },
...
```

Comment: probably when slots are swapped?

Comment: One other way could be to remove the `Identities` from the template and let the ARM deployment happen and thereafter assign identity using `New-AzureRmRoleAssignment` (Powershell).